# Nodejs: How to start a node application from a c++ program

Tags: c++, node.js

I am building an application where I build node from source and link its static libraries to my application. I would want my application to read a javascript file, initialise node and run the `js` file as a node application. However, I am not finding the right c++ node APIs to call to achieve this.  I am not even sure if this is possible. I only found [this](https://www.slideshare.net/nsm.nikhil/writing-native-bindings-to-nodejs-in-c)  link which seems to indicate that this is possible. Any idea how this can be done?

PS: Note that my application shouldn't have any "dynamic" parts.

**Edit**: The other question which is mentioned as dup doesn't explain how to initialise/start node and to run an application so keeping this question open

Comment: Why can't you use spawn or one of its variants to launch node with command line arguments?

Comment: C++ application I am talking about is a Unikernel. I am trying to port node to it. I need to figure out how to run these applications as node unikernel. I can't use the current node variants unfortunately

Comment: Since the question was unfortunately and incorrectly marked as duplicate, here is the answer to those who are looking for it: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1890

Comment: Here is another link which might be useful: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/818

Comment: I fail to see how it's not a duplicate.

Comment: The other question asks how to embed node as a interpreter. I’ve already embedded node , I just needed to find out how to start node by passing the js file. Mine is more specific while the other question is very broad. Hope this clarifies